# Stepper Motor Torque

Tags: robotic-arm, stepper-motor, torque, first-robotics

Tried searching for this answer in a simple way but can't seem to find the answer..

I have a 3 axis Bipolar Nema 17(Took off my 1st 3d printer =) ) robotic arm(Homemade) and provides 28oz-57oz of Torque as per datasheet,  now i am trying to figure out how much that can lift in Grams/lbs

Can anybody help?? Or if someone can give me a REALLY Simplified version on how to calculate and get the answer myself, which would be useful for future projects.

Thanxs
P

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, XVII. This question has (in a marginally different form) been asked and answered [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/9114/9720). If you review the question and answers there and still have questions, please edit this post or start a new one with those questions.